# How to Create/Run AsyncTask in Service without runOnUiThread()

Tags: android, multithreading, blocking, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a `Service` that creates `AsyncTask`s for downloading files. In activities, we create `Runnable`s or `Thread`s that we pass to `Activity.runOnUiThread()`. I can't access that method from a service, so how do I use `AsyncTask` correctly, (do heavy work without blocking the UI Thread)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your service is only called from your application, and you can make it a singleton, then try this:

```
public class FileDownloaderService extends Service implements FileDownloader {
    private static FileDownloaderService instance;

    public FileDownloaderService () {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This service is supposed to be a singleton");
        }
    }

    public static FileDownloaderService getInstance() {
        // TODO: Make sure instance is not null!
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(@SuppressWarnings("unused") Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void downloadFile(URL from, File to, ProgressListener progressListener) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Perform the file download
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Now you can directly call methods on your service. So just call `downloadFile()` to put the service to work.

About your *real* question of how to update the UI. Notice that this method receives a `ProgressListener` instance. It could look like this:

```
public interface ProgressListener {
    void startDownloading();
    void downloadProgress(int progress);
    void endOfDownload();
    void downloadFailed();
}
```

Now you just update the UI from the activity (not from the service, which remains unaware of how the UI looks like).

Comment: I think constructor `public FileDownloaderService ()` should be `private`. This is how Singletons should work ;-)

Comment: It's funny how you look at your own code from some months ago, and it already looks ugly to you :-O. You're right, it should be private. But I believe it won't work (neither my code in the answer), because the OS is gonna use the argument-less constructor to create the Service. Right?

Comment: It was a little suggestion only. I'm rather Android noob ;) but what's the problem in creating Sevice using argumentless constructor? As I know, `onProgressUpdate` from `AsyncTask` can update UI so maybe it would be a better solution.

Comment: If you're going to call Service methods directly, you might as well make it a generic Java object since you're completely bypassing the point of a Service. You don't instantiate a Service; the system does.